# Http 405: The requested resource does not support 'GET'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Hello i have a register method that am trying to use which is infact a POST but returns a Get. This happens on the production server.

```
   [RoutePrefix("register')]
   public class RegisterController : ApiController
   {
     private UserRepository userRepository;

    public RegisterController()
    {
        userRepository = new UserRepository();
    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(Users user)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result = await userRepository.RegisterUser(user);
        IHttpActionResult error = GetError(result);

        if(error != null)
        {
            return error;
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Tried this solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications with no success

Comment: We have to say [HttpPost] annotation for register method. Isnt it??

Comment: `is infact a POST but returns a Get.` I don't understand what that statement means.

Comment: Its supposed to return a POST error but i wonder why on Azure it returns a GET unsupported error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this problem before (405 : Method not allowed) and removing WebDav publish features resolved this. You can go to Add/Remove features and under IIS, try removing Web Dav publishing. Below screen shot taken from windows 10 console (it might vary depending upon server OS)

And yes, I believe [HttpPost] annotation is required.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your Register method to allow Post calls.

See below.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("register")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(Users user)
{
   //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you will have two register methods, one with get annotation to return the view and second with post annotation to create or register the user itself. I have created a new project and I can both as follows

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            // a lot goes in here
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```